# How would I sort an array of objects by one of its elements properties?

Tags: php, sorting, object

I have an array in PHP that is following this structure:

```
$soap->progress = `

0 =>
object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
  ["step"]=>
  int(6)
  ....
}

1 =>
object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
  ["step"]=>
  int(8)

....

}

2 =>
object(stdClass)#5 (5) {
  ["step"]=>
  int(1)

....

}

3 =>
object(stdClass)#6 (5) {
  ["step"]=>
  int(4)

....

}

4 =>
object(stdClass)#7 (5) {
  ["step"]=>
  int(3)
....
}


.... and so on
```

How would I sort this by `$soap->progress[x]->step`??

Comment: What you have here looks like it is an _array_ of objects, not an object as suggested by your question title.

Comment: Same as [Sort PHP array but the objects within](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954411/sort-php-array-but-the-objects-within) but replace `plannedCompletionDate` with `step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of these objects that you need to sort, you can use the `usort` function to define your own custom sorting callback:

```
usort($arrayOfObjects, function($a, $b) {
  if($a->step == $b->step) {
    return 0;
  else if($a->step > $b->step) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function sortByStep($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->step == $b->step) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->step < $b->step) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "sortByStep");
```

Comment: I get this error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Yes the answer is updated with accessing the step property instead of array index, just slightly confused by the brackets in your var_dump :)